# Trying to send datetime to controller via json

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

In my model I got a DateTime (FechaNac) format that I can't get it from a json.

```
public class Persona
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    [Required]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Apellido")]
    [Required]
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Fecha de nacimiento")]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime FechaNac { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Lugar")]
    [Required]
    public int Idlugar { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller I get most of the information of the model,

```
public JsonResult GetPostData(Persona jsonPersona)
{
  Console.WriteLine(jsonPersona.ToString());
  return Json(jsonPersona, "text/html", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

but I can't get the date, I tried a format it in javascript with in different ways with no success. The format is in ISO format (from the datepicker)

```
@using MVCprueba2.Models
@model MVCprueba2.Models.Persona
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Apellido, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Apellido)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaNac, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.JQueryUI().DatepickerFor(model => model.FechaNac)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Idlugar, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Idlugar)
    </div>
</div>
<div id="mensaje">Mensaje</div>
<p><input type="submit" value="Save" id="guardarPersona" /></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#guardarPersona").click(function () {
            var persona = new Object();
                persona.Nombre = $("#Nombre").val();
                persona.Apellido = $("#Apellido").val();
                persona.FechaNac = $('#FechaNac').datepicker("getDate"); //Solved [Typo]
                persona.Idlugar = $("#Idlugar").val();

            var jsonPersona = JSON.stringify(persona);
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetPostData")",
                type: "POST",
                data: jsonPersona,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
        });
        });
    });
</script>
```

But in the controller, sadly, I don't get the date, how can I fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working as expected

In the browser

> Fecha de nacimiento: 29.10.2014

In the controller

> FechaNac = {29.10.2014 00:00:00}